# Elasticsearch Append to Array in Golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go

Using elasticsearch 5.x and the olivere Elastic package.

I'm using the elastic package for Go to communicate with elasticsearch. Currently, I'm trying to append to an array within one of my JSON documents; however, I haven't been successful in doing so. How does one append to array fields in elasticsearch, using the olivere elastic package?

```
script := elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.Likes.add(Params.newCont)").Params(map[string]interface{}{"newCont" : newContent})
_, err = eclient.Update().
    Index(ENTRY_INDEX).
    Type(ENTRY_TYPE).
    Id("1").
    Script(script).
    Do(ctx)
```

Doing this does not successfully append anything to my array

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to include your code in question (if any). What you've tried so far? Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please add the query